# Generate CSV file and directly sent it with email laravel

Tags: laravel, csv, email

Halo guys, I New for laravel. Im using laravel 6 right now.  Now i am doing generate the CSV file and send it via E-mail.

the problem is:

1. I still confuse how do i can generate the CSV file and place it into server folder. let say that i want keep the CSV file into my server folder public/export/
2. How do i can sent generate CSV file via email.?

here is what i've done

```
        $reports = User::all()->get();
        $rows = [];
        foreach ($reports as $key => $value) {
            $rows[$key]['id'] = $value->social_media_id;
            $rows[$key]['name'] = $value->name;
            $rows[$key]['address'] = $value->address;
            $rows[$key]['phone'] = $value->phone; 
        } 

        $fileName = 'file.csv';
        $headers = [
            "Content-type" => "text/csv",
            "Content-Disposition" => "attachment; filename=" . $fileName,
            "Pragma" => "no-cache",
            "Cache-Control" => "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
            "Expires" => "0"
        ];

        $columnNames = [
            'ID',
            'name',
            'address',
            'phone'
        ];
        $callback = function() use ($columnNames, $rows ) {
            $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');
            fputcsv($file, $columnNames);
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                fputcsv($file, $row);
            }
            fclose($file);
        };
        return response()->stream($callback, 200, $headers));
```

how to modify this code for store the Generate CSV file in my server folder place on public/export/ ?

and then how do i can sent it via email?

please advice.

Comment: Any luck with figuring it out?

Comment: still not solve yet

Answer (score 2):

1. fputcsv() format line as CSV so you don't need $headers here. Also you don't need php://output because it's for sending to browser when you don't need to save it localy. So code will look something like this:

```
    $reports = User::all()->get();
    $fileName = 'file.csv';
    $columnNames = [
        'ID',
        'name',
        'address',
        'phone'
    ];
    
    $file = fopen('public/export/' . $fileName, 'w');
    fputcsv($file, $columnNames);
    
    foreach ($reports as $report) {
        fputcsv($file, [
             $report->id,
             $report->name,
             $report->address,
             $report->phone,
        ]);
    }
    
    fclose($file);
```

2. Fastest way to send email with this csv:

```
    Mail::send('your.email.blade.layout', [], function($message) use ($fileName)
    {
        $message->to('example@gmail.com')->subject('CSV email');
        $message->attach('public/export/' . $fileName);
    });
```

But it will be better if you will send via mailable class (docs: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail).

Also don't forget that you don't have a unique file name, so it will be overwritten every time.